# Cordova and executeSQL undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

I have a function in phonegap that I use to generate football fixtures.

The function puts id's of teams into an object and then loops through to input into WebSQL database.

The issue I have is the the executeSQL function inserts the last iteration  multiple times instead of each one separately.

the object:

```
[[{"home":3,"away":"--ghost--"},{"home":2,"away":1}],[{"away":1,"home":"--ghost--"},{"away":3,"home":2}],[{"away":2,"home":"--ghost--"},{"away":1,"home":3}]]
```

the function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < roundarray.length; i++) {
                    for (var n = 0; n < roundarray[i].length; n++) {
                        var home = roundarray[i][n]['home'];
                        var away = roundarray[i][n]['away'];
                        if (home != '--ghost--' && away != '--ghost--') {
                            console.log('home: '+home+', away: '+away+', league: '+league);
                            db.transaction(
                                function(tx) {
                                    insert_fixture(tx, home, away, league);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

the insert function:

```
function insert_fixture(tx, home, away, league) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO games (gameLeague, gameHome, gameAway) VALUES (?,?,?)', [league,home,away], 
            function(tx, rs) {
                console.log('home: '+home+', away: '+away+', league: '+league);
            }, errorCB);
    }
```

the console output:

```
2014-09-01 21:09:36.689 LoungeMode[2010:792512] [[{"home":3,"away":"--ghost--"},{"home":2,"away":1}],[{"away":1,"home":"--ghost--"},{"away":3,"home":2}],[{"away":2,"home":"--ghost--"},{"away":1,"home":3}]]
2014-09-01 21:09:36.690 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 2, away: 1, league: 1
2014-09-01 21:09:36.691 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 2, away: 3, league: 1
2014-09-01 21:09:36.691 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 3, away: 1, league: 1
2014-09-01 21:09:36.725 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 3, away: 1, league: 1
2014-09-01 21:09:36.737 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 3, away: 1, league: 1
2014-09-01 21:09:36.753 LoungeMode[2010:792512] home: 3, away: 1, league: 1
```

As you can see the first 3 console logs are what should be happening, whilst the last 3 are what's actually happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working using the following:

```
db.transaction(
                function(tx) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < roundarray.length; i++) {
                        var gamearray = roundarray[i];
                        for (var n = 0; n < gamearray.length; n++) {
                            var teamarray = gamearray[n];
                                        ht = teamarray['home'];
                                        at = teamarray['away'];
                                        if (ht != '--ghost--' && at != '--ghost--') {
                                            insert_fixture(tx, ht, at, league);
                                        }
                                    }


                        }

                }
              );
```